# Proving $\frac{π^2}8=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n - 1)^2}$ using Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I found the Fourier series of $x^2$, which is $$x^2 = \frac{π^2}{3} + 4 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} \cos(nx).$$
So now, how can I prove that $$\frac{π^2}{8} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n - 1)^2}? 
$$

Comment: Please show your try at the question, otherwise the post is prone to down votes.

Comment: For what values of $x$ does your Fourier series for $x^2$ hold?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: first set $x=\pi$ in the Fourier series and show that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{π^2}{6}$.

Comment: Not an answer to this question.  In fact, perhaps the OP is trying to prove $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$, and this is the first step in his proof... it can be done that way.

Comment: @GEdgar - my response is not a complete answer, but surely it is a first step ? Once you have a value for $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ from the Fourier series then deriving the sum of the odd terms is fairly straightforward.

Comment: I have made my hint more explicit. I will leave the OP to fill in the final step themselves.